# Power consumption of color e-ink?

Tags: e-ink

What is the power consumption in color e-ink based devices compared to black e-ink ones? Do the same principles apply here (for example, when image is still there is no power drain at all)?

To given some concrete devices as examples: HiSense A5 Pro CC (color) compared to HiSense A5 smartphone (b&w).